# Minimization of basis pursuit using ADMM

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

This [note](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) describes how to perform Basis Pursuit using the ADMM method. I am confused about how to map the general algorithm given in the note for this particular context. Can someone explain how it has been done here?

The general problem:
$$
\text{min}\ f(x) \qquad \text{s.t.}\ x \in C
$$
is equivalent to
$$
f(x) + g(z) \qquad \text{s.t.}\ x-z = 0
$$
where $g$ is the indicator function of C.
The augmented Lagrangian is written as
$$
f(x) + g(z) + 0.5\rho||x-z+u||_2^2
$$
which is solved iteratively as
\begin{align*}
x^{k+1} & = \text{min}\ f(x) + 0.5\rho||x-z^k+u^k||_2^2\\
z^{k+1} & = \prod_C(x^{k+1} + u^k)\\
u^{k+1} & = u^k + x^{k+1} - z^{k+1}
\end{align*}

Now consider the Basis Pursuit problem:
$$
||x||_1 \qquad \text{s.t.}\ Ax = b,
$$
They write it in ADMM form as
$$
||z||_1 + f(x) \qquad \text{s.t.}\ x - z = 0,
$$
and defines $f$ as the indicator function of $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax = b\}$ and write the algorithm as
\begin{align}
x^{k+1} & = \prod(z^k - u^k)\\
z^{k+1} & = S_{1/\rho}(x^{k+1} + u^k)\\
u^{k+1} & = u^k +x^{k+1} - z^{k+1}
\end{align}
where $\prod$ is the projection onto $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax = b\}$, and $S(\cdot)$ is the soft thresholding operator.
The update for $x$ is
$$
x^{k+1} = (I - A^\top (AA^\top)^{-1}A)(z^k - u^k) + A^\top(AA^\top)^{-1}b
$$

Comment: Where is your problem exactly : is it the general ADMM formulation adapted to basis pursuit or the way  updates are found ?

Comment: It is about how to use general formulas to get the updates.

Comment: Are you not using the formulas already? It seems that the updates you wrote down are exactly what you get if you apply the algorithm in Eqs. (3.5 - 3.7) of the note you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the proximal map
$$
\mathrm{prox}_f(\mathbf{y}) 
=
\textrm{argmin}_\mathbf{x}
\left[
f(\mathbf{x})+
\frac{1}{2}\| \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x} \|^2
\right]
$$
When $f(\mathbf{x})$ equals
the indicator $\delta_C(\mathbf{x})$ of a closed
convex set $C$, the proximal map
collapses to projection onto $C$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{x}^*
&=&
\mathrm{prox}_f(\mathbf{y}) =
P_C(\mathbf{y}) =
\mathbf{y}-
\mathbf{A}^T 
(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T)^{-1}
(\mathbf{Ay-b})
\end{eqnarray*}

When $f(\mathbf{x}) = \lambda\| \mathbf{x}\|_1$, the prox map is obtained through the soft-thresholding operator
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{x}^*
&=&
S_\lambda(\mathbf{y})
\end{eqnarray*}

From here, you will easily find the ADMM updates for basis pursuit
$$
\mathbf{x}^*=P_C(\mathbf{z-u}),
\mathbf{z}^*=
S_{1/\rho}(\mathbf{x}^* + \mathbf{u})
$$